# What happens to the old binary when a new one compiled from source?

Tags: linux, compiling, package-management, alternatives

I've compiled git from source after git from the repository was already installed via the package manager.

In that process, the "from source" git took its place as the "main system git".

```
user@jeanny:~$ git --version
git version 1.8.3.2
```

Is there a way to set the git from the repo as the "main system git"?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is exactly.  Which `git` will be used depends entirely upon value in `PATH` variable of the user invoking `git`.  Unless full path is used.

Comment: When i do `whereis git` i get `git: /usr/bin/git /usr/bin/X11/git /usr/local/bin/git` which lead me to think there are multiple binaries and that had something to do with `update-alternatives`.

Comment: Do `which git` instead.  That will give you the binary you will call when you type `git`.  You can set this in `alternatives` but you don't necessarily have to do that and your question is still unclear.

Comment: How did a copy of `git` end up in `/usr/bin/X11`? ... Oh, I see; on my system, `/usr/bin/X11` is a symlink to `/usr/bin`. On older systems, `/usr/bin/X11` was commonly a separate directory. Bottom line, you don't need to have `/usr/bin/X11` in your `$PATH`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can confirm this by doing the following:

```
$ /usr/bin/git --version

$ /usr/local/bin/git --version
```

It's likely that you now have 2 versions of `git` installed which is completely fine, so long as they're kept in separate directories.

The newly compiled version of `git` is most likely the one in the directory `/usr/local/bin`.

You can use the `$PATH` environment variable to control which `git` gets used by controlling the order of how things appear in the `$PATH`.

For example:

- system version of `git` is the default

  ```
  PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin
  ```
- newly compiled version of `git` is the default

  ```
  PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin
  ```

#### What about alternatives?

The OP asked the following follow-up question in the comments:

> Where does update-alternatives fit into this picture?

[Alternatives is a mechanism](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl8_alternatives.htm) that allows your system to incorporate tools that aren't installed in `/usr/bin` to be accessible through `/usr/bin` by putting a link in the `/usr/bin` directory that is then managed by software. An example says it best. On my system, Java is managed as an alternatives app:

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/java
lrwxrwxrwx. 1 root root 22 Dec 26  2010 /usr/bin/java -> /etc/alternatives/java
```

You can tell because of the above link under `/usr/bin`. Given this is a link managed by alternatives doesn't change the fact that the link is still under the directory `/usr/bin`. So when we manipulate the `$PATH` as described above, alternatives is a non-issue.

Comment: Where does `update-alternatives` fit into this picture?

Comment: do an `echo $PATH` and see which git bin directory it points to. This will be the "active" git version. To change it, just set your PATH to include that other version's bin directory.

Comment: @Alan - see updates regarding alternatives.